# xsl:variable ignores <br />

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

If I do something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="something">
  <xsl:value-of select="node1" /><br />
  <xsl:value-of select="node2" /><br />
  <xsl:value-of select="node3" /><br />
  <xsl:value-of select="node4" /><br />
</xsl:variable>

<h1><xsl:value-of select="$something" /></h1>
```

The line breaks are ignored. Is that right?

I'm using xslt 1.0 if that makes any difference.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using **xsl:copy-of** here, not **xsl:value-of** because **xsl:value-of** only outputs the text value of a node

```
 <h1><xsl:copy-of select="$something" /></h1>
```

Comment: Brilliant.Think that proves a little knowledge can be dangerous. Thanks for you help. Will accept your answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `copy-of` instead of `value-of` in order to maintain the `<br/>`. The reason is that the `value-of` looks for the text of the node that you select so if you want the text and the elements of that node you would need the copy and not the value.

Since you are using XSLT 1.0 you may also want to look into `exslt:node-set` for better handling of result tree fragments like this.

As a side note, your `h1` is being closed by an `h2` which is not valid. Hopefully that was just a copy and paste error.

Comment: Oops. Thanks for pointing out the typo. Fixed it now. And thanks for the tips.